# R: write complex data frame as is to a file

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
>results[,1:4]

           N=9                                                                      N=8                                            N=7                                                      N=6
HPS4\n(244,492) APOL3\n(235,486)\nAPOL5\n(200,398)\nCELSR1\n(213,432)\nCLTCL1\n(204,402) CPT1B,CHKB-CPT1B\n(175,344)\nPLXNB2\n(205,412) FAM118A\n(121,240)\nMYO18B\n(169,345)\nSEC14L4\n(99,221)
```

N=9, N=8, N=7...until N=1 is the first row. The second row has comma- & newline-separated values. The dimensions of my data frame are:

```
dim(results)
[1] 2 9

class(results)
[1] "data.frame"
```

The problem is that I have tried write.table() using different separator values as well as WriteXLS (of the WriteXLS package) but every single time the output file is messed up. The first row outputs nicely, but the second row gets appended all in the first 2-3 columns. Basically the table does not output *as is*. I would like to know alternatives where you can write the dataframe without losing the separators between the columns.

```
dput(results)
structure(list(X9 = c("N=9", "HPS4\n(244,492)"), X8 = c("N=8", 
"APOL3\n(235,486)\nAPOL5\n(200,398)\nCELSR1\n(213,432)\nCLTCL1\n(204,402)"
), X7 = c("N=7", "CPT1B,CHKB-CPT1B\n(175,344)\nPLXNB2\n(205,412)"
), X6 = c("N=6", "FAM118A\n(121,240)\nMYO18B\n(169,345)\nSEC14L4\n(99,221)"
), X5 = c("N=5", "MOV10L1\n(97,230)"), X4 = c("N=4", "CCDC157\n(95,212)\nCECR2\n(121,272)\nSEC14L3\n(93,178)\nTTLL12\n(128,241)\nTXNRD2\n(144,302)\nYDJC,CCDC116\n(108,224)"
), X3 = c("N=3", "CARD10\n(78,165)\nEFCAB6\n(38,69)\nIL17RA\n(59,112)\nPLA2G3\n(69,134)\nRIBC2\n(84,163)\nRTDR1\n(1,2)\nSLC2A11\n(21,53)\nTEX33\n(39,73)\nTTC38\n(14,30)"
), X2 = c("N=2", "APOBEC3H\n(109,233)\nBRD1\n(33,67)\nGNB1L\n(12,31)\nMN1\n(26,52)\nPRAME\n(15,38)\nPRR14L\n(53,109)\nSCARF2\n(80,193)\nSMC1B\n(30,55)\nSUN2\n(73,128)\nTBC1D10A\n(53,129)\nTUBGCP6\n(81,160)\nTYMP,SCO2\n(41,88)"
), X1 = c("N=1", "ALG12\n(58,107)\nAPOBEC3G\n(31,67)\nARVCF\n(7,20)\nBCL2L13\n(6,13)\nBCR\n(9,19)\nCABIN1\n(51,99)\nCDC42EP1\n(5,7)\nCDPF1\n(36,56)\nCRELD2\n(87,159)\nCRYBA4\n(16,26)\nCSNK1E\n(0,1)\nEFCAB6,EFCAB6-AS1\n(1,0)\nEMID1\n(17,26)\nFAM109B\n(0,2)\nFAM227A\n(0,5)\nFAM83F\n(0,4)\nGAB4\n(19,40)\nGGT1,FAM211B\n(0,4)\nGGT5\n(23,37)\nHDAC10\n(35,71)\nISX\n(32,59)\nKCTD17\n(0,0)\nMICAL3\n(6,15)\nPACSIN2\n(5,9)\nPEX26\n(14,20)\nPIWIL3\n(36,60)\nPNPLA3\n(96,171)\nPNPLA5\n(20,19)\nPPP6R2\n(3,5)\nSCUBE1\n(2,3)\nSELO\n(10,18)\nSEZ6L\n(14,30)\nSGSM1\n(14,37)\nTBX1\n(99,184)\nTCN2\n(31,57)\nTMPRSS6\n(4,17)\nTRMU\n(39,84)\nZBED4\n(1,0)\nZNF74\n(1,9)"
)), .Names = c("X9", "X8", "X7", "X6", "X5", "X4", "X3", "X2", 
"X1"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")
```

[This](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bqvw3cgakbeus52/results.xls?dl=0) is the kind of output I am expecting.

I just want to **make a file** out of it, **in any format**, but **representing exactly the kind of** **table** that I have shown **in the link**. I do not want to import it again in R or any other software.

Comment: Where is this going eventually? If its going back into R then use `save` or `saveRDS`. Otherwise if you need a CSV then you'll have to convert the newlines into escaped newlines somehow...

Comment: It should be written to a file. Not R. And I do require the commas and the new lines. It is part of how the file should be written out.

Comment: What output are you expecting? Please post an example of that, since it’s not clear at all.

Comment: Its important to know what you are doing with the file. CSVs with real newlines in the data are odd, and I doubt much software will handle it, thinking there's a real newline and insufficient fields.

Comment: I have updated my question with the link to the kind of output I am expecting.

Comment: If you want to create a spreadsheet I think your best bet is to do it manually using something like the `xlsx` package rather than go via an intermediate and poorly-specced CSV file.

Comment: It doesn't matter if its a spreadsheet or a simple txt file as long as I can make a table like that. I do want the \n to be interpreted as new lines. Also, I did try the WriteXLS package (as mentioned in my question) but it creates a .xls file which does not have proper the output.

Comment: @Komal Rathi: please edit the question for basic clarity on what you want to achieve. You want to do a one-way export to some structured (text/spreadsheet) file format, any format will do. You then intend to import it somewhere else (where?) and do something with that (what?).

Comment: I just want to make a file out of it, in any format, representing a table that I have shown in the link. I do not want to import it again in R or any other software, if thats what you mean.

Comment: Please include all parts of the question here. Link may go dead without notice (especially Dropbox), rendering the question less useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I simply:

```
> write.csv(results,"results.csv")
```

then read into Open/Libre Office spreadsheet:

[image]

which looks like your sample spreadsheet output. Chop the heading and first column out if you want.

Did you try this? Does Excel fail? Install Open/Libre office instead.

Note your dropbox example had no newline between "ALG12 (58,107)" 
whereas your sample data does, so my J3 cell is a bit crammed and falls off the bottom.